# How I Can Show Marks and Their course In a Row in Java?

Tags: java, android, read-eval-print-loop

This is my main class

```
FurtherInfo furtherinfo = new FurtherInfo("Android", 70);

 FurtherInfo[] list = new FurtherInfo[4];

            list[0] = furtherinfo;
            list[1] = new FurtherInfo ("php", 25);
            list[2] = new FurtherInfo ("html", 20);
            list[3] = new FurtherInfo ("css", 5); 

Student student = new Student("Emraan" ,22, list);

student.print();
```

when i run project its look like this,

```
name    Emraan

age 22

marks:  70, course  Android

marks:  25, course  php

marks:  20, course  html

marks:  5, course   css
```

I just want to change one thing, course and marks should be shown like this

Details just in one row

```
marks: 70 course android, marks 25 course php, marks 20 course html, marks 5 course css
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is inside `print` ?

Comment: name Emraan

age 22

marks: 70, course Android

marks: 25, course php

marks: 20, course html
marks: 5, course css

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer i just need to use print method instead of println method

like this

System.out.print("Abc," 000)